# Why does QPushButton not respect absolute pixel size?

Tags: resize, pyqt4, qpushbutton

I'm working on an application that's running on an embedded device with a touch LCD screen. For development setup, I have setup a Xephyr window with the matchbox WM at the same resolution (1280x800).

I have deloped a customer dropdown menu that will expand down wards and show select buttons, on my dev system this looks 9as designed) something like this:
[image]

Where on the end device, the button fills the whole window as can be seen here:

[image]

The functionality seems there but even though fix pixel sizes are used for the button size, it seems to take up the space of the whole window. They "drop-down" buttons are created from a list like:

```
btn_size = QtCore.QSize(206,57)

        for n in btnlist:
            _name = str(n)
            self.drpbtns.append(QtGui.QPushButton(_name))
            self.drpbtns[i].clicked.connect(lambda checked, v=_name: func(v))
            self.drpbtns[i].resize(btn_size)
            self.drpbtns[i].move(x,y+(i*(self.drpbtns[i].height()-1)))
            self.drpbtns[i].setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(255,255,255); \
                                           border: 1px solid rgb(216,216,216); \
                                           color: rgb(92,92,92); \
                                           font: bold 22pt "Avenir"')
            self.drpbtns[i].setFlat(True)


            i = i+1
```

Why would the buttons not respect the `QSize()` as assigned?

I have started a new thread in the [Qt Forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/125462/why-does-qpushbutton-not-respect-absolute-pixel-size) at and will make sure that replies are cross populated between the two threads!

Comment: change `resize` to `setFixedSize`

Comment: @eyllanesc that's it? I unfortunately cannot test/verify it until on Monday. Like always, your feedback is super appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Without more context is hard to give you a more comprehensive answer, but if you're adding those buttons to a layout, trying to set both the size (unless a size constraint is set) and the position is completely useless: they are called layout managers because they *manage* the layout, they decide where widgets should be placed and how big they should be. This also means that if you *are* using a layout, while setting the fixed size will work, moving will not. If you still face similar problems, I suggest you to edit your question and provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: While it turns out that `setFixedSize()` did not actually fix the problem (the button still blows up to cover the complete visible space), I can say that layouts are being used underneath and I just wanted to use fix positioned buttons for this customized "drop down widget". I'll have to work on a minimal reproducible example when I go to the office next time (as I don't currently have access to a simulated unit that let's me duplicate this issue).... Is there anything else I could try out in the meantime, instead?

Comment: resizing the visivle area is not of concern in this example as we're fixed at using the 1280x800 LCD display and there's no option to the user to resize the visible area at all (full screen touch interface)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And turns out, I have found the solution to my problem here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/78752/how-to-place-widgets-by-specifying-positions-in-qframe

I changed my `QPushButton` line to include the parent which resolved the issue: `self.drpbtns.append(QtGui.QPushButton(_name,self.parent))`